# How to create a nested ngrx-forms which can add or remove controls to it's child groups?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

How to create a nested ngrx-forms which can add or remove controls to its child groups?

Here I want to create a form with two subgroups languages & topics

```
export interface LanguageFormValue {
    languages: { [id: string]: { language: string, min: number, max: number } };
    preferredLanguage: string;
}

export interface TopicFormValue { 
    favoriteTopic: string; 
    otherTopics: {[id: string]: { [id: string]: boolean }}
 };

export interface AddNewEntryFormValue {
  languages: LanguageFormValue
  topics: TopicsFormValue;
}

export interface AddNewEntryFormState extends RootState {
  newEntry: {
    languages: {
      formState: FormGroupState<LanguageFormValue>;
      languageOptions: string[];
    };
    topics: {
    formState: FormGroupState<TopicsFormValue>;
    topicsOptions: string[];
  };
  };

}
```

Actions for adding topics

```
export class CreateTopicControlAction implements Action {
  static readonly TYPE = '[Entry Form] Add Topic Control';
  readonly type = CreateTopicControlAction.TYPE;
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}
```

Actions for languages

```
export class CreateLanguageControlAction implements Action {
  static readonly TYPE = '[Entry Form] Add Language Control';
  readonly type = CreateGroupElementAction.TYPE;
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}

export class RemoveLanguageControlAction implements Action {
  static readonly TYPE = '[Entry Form] Remove Language Control';
  readonly type = RemoveGroupElementAction.TYPE;
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}
```

How can I write a reducer for the above form?

I've tried many ways, but the reducer is showing errors?

Is there any way to combine sub formGroupStates while retaining the ability to add or remove controls in those substates?

I've tried making 'filterBy' as the parent Form group and tried adding reducers for the child languages & topics groups. But that failed.

I've also tried splitting each of the languages and topics separately to different reducer.ts files. But then I will have to register each of them storeModule.forFeature() separately. It was working, But this is changing my state tree structure (which is not what I want). So I tried grouping the states and reducers of these separated reducer files using an index.ts and tried registering it as a feature. But that also failed as the controls becomes undefined.

I've tried a couple other ways... But noting is working.

Is there any way to combine sub formGroupStates while retaining the ability to add or remove controls in those substates?

or we can make it like this : but still wanna retain adding or removing functionalities for child groups (languages & topics)

```
export interface FilterByState extends RootState {
  filterBy: formState: FormGroupState<FilterFormValue>;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of [ngrx-forms](https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms) here.

The following should work (using ngrx v8+). I also recommend you create your actions with ngrx v8+ style, otherwise you cannot properly use the modern reducer style.

```js
const createTopicControl = createAction('[Entry Form] Add Topic Control', (name: string) => ({ name }));
const createLanguageControl = createAction('[Entry Form] Add Language Control', (name: string) => ({ name }));
const removeLanguageControl = createAction('[Entry Form] Remove Language Control', (name: string) => ({ name }));

const initialState: AddNewEntryFormState = {
  newEntry: {
    languages: {
      formState: createFormGroupState<LanguageFormValue>('LANGUAGES_FORM', {
        languages: {},
        preferredLanguage: '',
      }),
      languageOptions: [],
    },
    topics: {
      formState: createFormGroupState<TopicFormValue>('TOPICS_FORM', {
        favoriteTopic: '',
        otherTopics: {},
      }),
      topicsOptions: [],
    },
  }
}

export const addNewEntryFormStateReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  onNgrxForms(),
  on(createTopicControl, (state, { name }) => {
    // yes, nested reducers are ugly, look at options like immer.js
    // to make this less messy
    return {
      ...state,
      newEntry: {
        ...state.newEntry,
        topics: {
          ...state.newEntry.topics,
          formState: updateGroup(state.newEntry.topics.formState, {
            otherTopics: addGroupControl(name, {}),
          }),
        },
      },
    };
  }),
  on(createLanguageControl, (state, { name }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      newEntry: {
        ...state.newEntry,
        languages: {
          ...state.newEntry.languages,
          formState: updateGroup(state.newEntry.languages.formState, {
            languages: addGroupControl(name, {
              language: '',
              min: 0,
              max: 0,
            }),
          }),
        },
      },
    };
  }),
  on(removeLanguageControl, (state, { name }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      newEntry: {
        ...state.newEntry,
        languages: {
          ...state.newEntry.languages,
          formState: updateGroup(state.newEntry.languages.formState, {
            languages: removeGroupControl(name),
          }),
        },
      },
    };
  }),
);
```

I hope this helps.